# Normal build fail. But archive get success

Tags: ios, xcode8

Suddenly I cant build or run the project on my device. It says unresolved identifier for one method. But I can run on semulator without any issue also archive get success. And if I made a build using distribution profile then also it doesnt give any error. And I can download and install on my device without any issue. However I submitted the app to appstore since my archive get success. And I didnt even get a invalid binary notification. Now my app is in review state. I am afraid if it reject in any case. Please give your ideas or do you have any experience like this? Please help me.

Comment: As matt already told you, please do not re-ask the same question. That is considered "noise" on Stack Overflow. If you don't get an answer, then what you can do is edit your question. We have more advice on how to ask a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). But please don't delete your old question and ask it again; that will quickly get your account suspended. I've undeleted the original question (since it has more details), and merged the answers from here over there.